# Loop through array values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a small problem:

I need to repeat this

```
do {
    $QUERY = "/member?id=".$counter."&action=refresh";
    $URL = $HTTP.$HTTPUSER.":".$HTTPPASS."@".$HTTPSERVER.":".$HTTPPORT.$QUERY;
    $xml = file_get_contents($URL);

    $data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $test_ip = (string)$data->c1;

    $dnsip = explode('<br>', $test_ip);

    $ext_ip = strip_tags($dnsip[1]);

    if ($ext_ip != "127.0.0.1" && $ext_ip != "localhost") {

        $dns = strip_tags($dnsip[0]);

        echo "$dns $ext_ip <br>";
    }

    $counter +=1;

} while (!empty($data));
```

as many times as there are values inside an array, so i tried to add this

```
    $ports  = array('2001','2002','2003'); 

foreach ($ports as $HTTPPORT) {

echo "$HTTPPORT<br>";

$counter = 1;

do {
    $QUERY = "/member?id=".$counter."&action=refresh";
    $URL = $HTTP.$HTTPUSER.":".$HTTPPASS."@".$HTTPSERVER.":".$HTTPPORT.$QUERY;
    $xml = file_get_contents($URL);

    $data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $test_ip = (string)$data->c1;

    $dnsip = explode('<br>', $test_ip);

    $ext_ip = strip_tags($dnsip[1]);

    if ($ext_ip != "127.0.0.1" && $ext_ip != "localhost") {

        $dns = strip_tags($dnsip[0]);

        echo "$dns $ext_ip <br>";
    }

    $counter +=1;

} while (!empty($data)); }
```

The problem is that it executes the script with only first port number (2001), and i can't discover why.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe you get stuck in your do while loop. Is $data ever empty?

Comment: Yes, after it finishes the while loop for port 2001 it exits normally, but doesn't continue to do the same with other 2 ports...really don't know what is happening, i can't find any errors

Comment: What language is this, PHP? Please add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Amended code to do more sensible things now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be getting an exception inside your 'do .. while' loop that is causing bother.

I have added a 'try .. catch' block and some 'echo' statements to ensure it always loops round all the 'ports' now. Changed 'catch' to mark $data as empty then continue.

here is tested code:

```
<?php

$ports  = array('2001','2002','2003');

$counter = 0; // total count of documents

foreach($ports as $HTTPPORT) {

    echo $HTTPPORT, ' start of process port loop<br/>';

    try { // catch any error -- report it and loop round again
        do {
            $QUERY = "/member?id=".$counter."&action=refresh";
            $URL = ''; // $HTTP.$HTTPUSER.":".$HTTPPASS."@".$HTTPSERVER.":".$HTTPPORT.$QUERY;
            try {
                $xml = file_get_contents($URL);
                $data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) { // ignore any errors
                echo 'SimpleXMLElement : oops :', $e->getMessage(), '<br />';
                $data = ''; // mark as empty
            }

            if (!empty($data)) { // process data
                $test_ip = (string)$data->c1;
                $dnsip = explode('<br>', $test_ip);

                $ext_ip = strip_tags($dnsip[1]);

                if ($ext_ip != "127.0.0.1" && $ext_ip != "localhost") {

                    $dns = strip_tags($dnsip[0]);

                    echo "$dns $ext_ip <br>";
                }
            }

            $counter +=1;

        } while (!empty($data));

    } // end of try to get and process a document...
    catch (Exception $e) { // catch all errors for now
        echo 'Processing List of Ports: oops! :', $e->getMessage(), '<br />';
    }
} // end of foreach port
```

Comment: This works, the thing is when while loop gets to the end of one loop, it reports an error instead of breaking the loop and continuing with another port...is there a better way to loop through id's untill it gets no contents from a page?